# Nunit Base Text Fixtures and the order in which they run

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

If I have:

```
[TestFixture]
public class BaseTestFixture
{
  [TestFixtureSetup]
  public void SetUpStuff()
  {

  }
}

[TestFixture]
public class DeriveTestFixture : BaseTextFixture
{
   [TestFixtureSetup]
   public void SetupOtherStuff()
   {
   } 
}
```

Does the BaseTextFixture TestFixtureSetup method get called before or after the DerivedTestFixture TestFixtureSetUp method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not prove it to yourself with the test?

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class BaseTestFixture
    {
      [TestFixtureSetup]
      public void SetUpStuff()
      {
         Console.Writeline("Base");
      }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class DeriveTestFixture : BaseTextFixture
    {
       [TestFixtureSetup]
       public void SetupOtherStuff()
       {
         Console.Writeline("Derived");
       } 
    }
```

That said you might think about only having the attributes on the base and having two other functions to override such as OnAfterTestFixtureSetup() so it's more explicit.  That is,

```
[TestFixture]
    public class BaseTextFixture
    {
      [TestFixtureSetup]
      public void SetUpStuff()
      {
         Console.Writeline("Base");
        OnAfterTextFixtureSetup();
      }

      public virtual OnAfterTextFixtureSetup()
      {

      }
}
```